# Rendering an image over JButtons

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a game using swing with a JPanel for level selection and JButtons set up for navigating to the levels. I've also created a .png image for the entire level screen - is it possible to render the image on top of the JButtons? If not, what's the simplest alternative?

Comment: Do you want to have a single image over all the buttons, or do you want a button to have an image on it?

Comment: Use the approach shown in this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/230513).

Comment: Why make a game using swing? Swing is not for making games. You have so many other good options for java like libgdx, slick2d (it is old), etc. Also if you want to work a little harder, you can use lwjgl.

Comment: I have to use swing because it's for a school assignment

Comment: One image over all buttons

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want to do is possible, but my approach has usually been to use a mouse listener instead. Just check for clicks within a certain area handle them.